# Definitory question about tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M,N$ be modules over a a ring $R$, and consider the tensor product $M\otimes_RN$. From what I understood $M\otimes_RN$ is the quotient of the free $R$-module over $M\times N$ by the relation $\sim$ defined as follows: $$(m+m',n)\sim (m,n)+(m',n);$$ $$(m,n+n')\sim (m,n)+(m,n');$$ $$(rm,n)\sim (m,rn).$$ In particular $(m,n)$ is in relation with another pair $(m',n')$ if and only if one these two situations is verified: $$\exists r\in R:m=rm', n'=rn;$$ $$\exists r\in R:n=rn', m'=rm.$$ Now, supposing that the  first situation occurs, it can happen that $m,n\neq 0$ and $rn=0$, so that $(m,n)\sim (m',0)$; it  is also easy to see that $(m',0)\sim(0,0)$. However I'm having troubles in understanding how come $(m,n)\sim (0,0)$, that as $\sim$ is transitive, must be true. In fact  since $m\neq 0$ also $m'\neq 0$, meaning that  $(m',n')$ cannot be $(0,0)$. I hope is just a misunderstanding that can be solved easily, but personally I've spent more than an hour on this problem, and I still don't understand.

Comment: I think in general when we quotient out by certain relations, those relations generate a lot more "interactions" than just what the relations give at face value. For example, given a free group on three elements $\{a,b,c\}$ quotiented by the relations $a^{−1}ba = b^2, b^{−1}cb = c^2, c^{−1}ac = a^2$, it turns out these relations "conspire" to actually force the relations $a=b=c=e$ (or in other words, the group given by the generators-and-relations definition $\langle a,b,c \mid a^{−1}ba = b^2, b^{−1}cb = c^2, c^{−1}ac = a^2 \rangle$ is actually trivial $ = \{e\}$).

Comment: Ok but what I'm thinking is that on the elements of $M\times N$ (that is contained in the free group over itself obviously) the only relation that remains is the third one; and I don't understand how this is a transitive relation.

Comment: I'm saying that as it's defined $\sim$ is *not* an equivalence relation; the relation is actually the "smallest" equivalence relation *generated* by those 3 rules. In the theory of free groups, the analogy is that $\langle{X \mid R}\rangle$ is defined as $\text{Free}(X)/\langle\langle R \rangle\rangle$, i.e. we must quotient by the normal subgroup *generated* by $R$ in order to get to a group that satisfies just the relations $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that $M\otimes_R N$ is the quotient of the free module by the equivalence relation $\sim$ you describe.  Indeed, $\sim$ is not even an equivalence relation--it is not typically transitive or symmetric.  Instead, $M\otimes_R N$ is defined as the quotient by the submodule of the free module *generated* by all elements of the form $$(m+m',n)-(m,n)-(m',n),$$ $$(m,n+n')-(m,n)-(m,n'),$$ $$(rm,n)-r(m,n),$$ or $$(m,rn)-r(m,n).$$  Or intuitively, you take a quotient by the relation $\sim$, but you make all further identifications that are forced on you in order for the quotient to still have a natural $R$-module structure (including both the identifications needed to get an actual equivalence relation, but also more since that equivalence relation additionally must respect the $R$-module operations).

(Also, the third case in your definition of $\sim$ is wrong: you need to not just identify $(rm,n)$ with $(m,rn)$, but also identify these with $r(m,n)$.  Alternatively, your third case would be correct if you were starting with the free *abelian group* on $M\times N$ instead of the free $R$-module.)

Comment: So it seems hard to determine if a pair $(m,n)$ (say with $m,n\neq 0$), is or not zero in the tensor product. My naive intuition was to check if among all the elements of the free module of the form $rr'(m',n')$, where $rm'=m,r'n=n'$, there is one that is zero: i.e., either $rr'=0$, $r\in\operatorname{Ann}N$ or $r'\in\operatorname{Ann}M$. However as you pointed out the elements of that form are not all the elements in relation to $(m,n)$ in the free module; meaning that maybe there aren't zero element of that form, but $(m,n)$ can still be zero in the tensor.

Comment: I don't know if I made clear my problem, but I don't really want a solution; I would just like to know if it is actually a problem or it's just me overthinking over something that could  be made simple. Anyway thanks for your answer, it was very clear

Comment: I don't think there's any simple criterion for when $(m,n)$ is zero in the tensor product.